# Getting a proper reference for a presentation

Tags: bibtex, lyx

I wish to reference a presentation in my PhD thesis.

(URL is https://samate.nist.gov/docs/SwMM-RSV2016/SwMM-RSV_13_UsingMalwareAnalysis_CWoody.pdf)

Try as I might I cannot get anything better (using Bibtex) than this:

[155] Carol Woody. Using malware analysis to reduce design weaknesses, 2016.

Which, to be honest, isn't very useful or convincing - as it gives no direct information on how to access the reference.

What settings should I use in Bibtex so I at least get the URL to appear as part of the reference?

(The thesis itself is on LyX and the style format is "Basic (BibTeX)" - I have used a variety of BibTeX types in a search for a better representation eg url/electronic/webpage and probably others too - but none seem to work for me.)

Comment: Please tell us which bibliography style you employ and which entry type you use.

Comment: Thanks - have added now

Comment: Since you're using lyx, you may want to post a query to the lyx support page. (I'm not a lyx user, and I've never heard of a bibliography style called "Basic (BibTeX)" before today.)